# is ball movement count if the golf is affected by wild animals?

Tags: golf

For instance, if a squirrel picks away the golf, is it count for movement or just remain the original position?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would come under Rule 18 - [Ball at rest moved by outside agency](http://www.randa.org/en/Rules-and-Amateur-Status/Rules-of-Golf.aspx#/rules/?ruleNum=18&subRuleNum=1)

Essentially there is no penalty to the player, and the ball should be replaced. Note that you need to be sure it was an outside agency that moved the ball - neither wind nor water count.